# Magento 2: TAX Calculation / Approximation not correct

Tags: magento2, tax

I have set up a TAX rate of 4%.

I've then received different orders, but I've found that the tax calculation is not correct, or better, the approximation isn't.

That's an example:

The client bought an item for the price of € 3.37.

4% should be 0.1348, but Magento just cut it off at 0.13.
The right approximation should be 0.14 instead.

Of course then the final total price is off.

How is it possible to fix it? Thank you.